# How To : Create-React-App : Move Build project folder to CDN

Tags: npm, create-react-app, cdn

We are using `create-react-app` for app react application. We used to do `npm run build` in the production web server. I would like to know whether it possible to move the build files (project files) into a CDN network so that SPA load fast from CDN ?

Thanks,
Raja

Answer (score 0):

You can point the build files to a CDN by setting the following environment variable in your build site:

```
PUBLIC_URL = http://example.com/path/to/cdn/
```

[image]